# Calculate monthly close conversion rate of total customer created in same month vs how many of them converted in sale

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE data (account_id int, cust_status varchar(25), amount int, date date);

INSERT INTO data VALUES
    ('1', 'first_login', '1000', '01/01/2021'),
    ('1', 'sale',        '500',  '28/01/2021'),
    ('2', 'first_login', '2000', '07/03/2021'),
    ('3', 'first_login', '1000', '01/06/2021'),
    ('3', 'sale',        '2000', '05/08/2021'),
    ('4', 'first_login', '5000', '18/06/2021'),
    ('4', 'sale',        '3000', '18/09/2021'),
    ('5', 'first_login', '5000', '02/06/2021'),
    ('6', 'first_login', '2000', '11/06/2021'),
    ('7', 'first_login', '1000', '22/06/2021'),
    ('8', 'first_login', '3000', '29/06/2021');
```

Here is data from that table:

| acc_id | cust_status | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | first_login | 1000 | 01/01/2021 |
| 1 | sale | 500 | 28/01/2021 |
| 2 | first_login | 2000 | 07/03/2021 |
| 3 | first_login | 1000 | 01/06/2021 |
| 3 | sale | 2000 | 05/08/2021 |
| 4 | first_login | 5000 | 18/06/2021 |
| 4 | sale | 3000 | 18/09/2021 |
| 5 | first_login | 5000 | 02/06/2021 |
| 6 | first_login | 2000 | 11/06/2021 |
| 7 | first_login | 1000 | 22/06/2021 |
| 8 | first_login | 3000 | 29/06/2021 |

I need to calculate what is the conversion rate for customer every month.

Total account has created as `first_login` in month and how many of them converted into sale later.

I tried to calculate the result based on the formulas but stuck at how to make self/inner join in order to bring desired result.

Result should look like:

| close rate | close vol rate | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100% | 50% | January |
| 0 | 0 | March |
| 33.3% | 29.41% | June |

As in June there are 6 account created as `first_login` and only 2 of them later converted into sale.

- conversion close rate = count(sale)/count(first_login)*100
- conversion close vol rate = sum(sale)/sum(first_login)*100

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Also, columns you trying to insert are different than definition

Comment: @Tushar, is `DATE` really a Postgresql reserved word? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words

Comment: You are right @jarlh; It's not a reserved keyword. 
I created a sqlfiddle with this data and got syntax error at date place.
But it was for String datatype. My mistake

Comment: There are 6 `first_login`s in June But no sale as pert your data.
And
Your expected output is different; Can you change either your Input Table (Data)

OR  Expected output as per fomula ?

Comment: Hello @Tushar, I am sorry for the error in the table. I wanted to calculate num,ber of leads generated in June (6) and how many of them get sale in later (2). (Account_id is same in both cases).

Comment: OK,
I got it now. I will change my query as per it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do a left join and aggregate using filters with sum and count functions as the following:

```
select 
  coalesce
  (
   round
   (
     count(*) filter (where t2.cust_status ='sale')/
     nullif(count(*) filter (where t1.cust_status ='first_login'), 0)::numeric *100
    , 2
   ), 0
  ) as "close rate",
  coalesce
  (
    round
    (
      sum(t2.amount) filter (where t2.cust_status ='sale')/
      nullif(sum(t1.amount) filter (where t1.cust_status ='first_login'), 0)::numeric *100
      , 2
    ), 0
  ) as "close vol rate",
  to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM') as "month"
from tbl_name t1 left join tbl_name t2
on t1.acc_id = t2.acc_id and
   t1.cust_status <> t2.cust_status
group by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM')
order by to_char(t1.date, 'YYYY-MM')
```

The `nullif` is used to avoid division by zero, and `coalesce` is used to replace nulls by zero.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/M8CZvlrI)

Comment: hello @ahmed, Thank you for the solution. But when I am applying **filter** in my code it is not working and throwing error - **Syntax error : Expected ")"**. Can you please help me here as well.

Comment: What version of postgresql you have?

Comment: If your version does not support filters, try using conditional aggregation as [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/IKnrin3j)

Answer (score 0):

I imported your data to [DBFIDDLE and here is a working demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/LFjbwtVb)

The following query shall get you the output in Expected format.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'sale' THEN account_id END) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'sale' THEN account_id END) / NULLIF(COUNT(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'first_login' THEN account_id END), 0), 2)
    END AS close_rate,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'sale' THEN amount END) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE ROUND(100.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'sale' THEN amount END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN cust_status = 'first_login' THEN amount END), 0), 2)
    END AS close_vol_rate,
   to_char(date_trunc('month', date), 'Month') AS month
FROM data
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', date)
ORDER BY date_trunc('month', date);
```

The query with your fomulae will throw a division by zero error if there are no first_login events for a particular month. In order to handle this, I have used the `NULLIF` function to return a null value instead of zero if the denominator is zero.

This gives same output as manually calculated output :

| close rate | close vol rate | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100% | 50% | January |
| 0 | 0 | March |
| 0 | null | June |
| null | null | August |
| null | null | September |